# Javascript Variable from form element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to trigger a javascript function which captures the order Id and also the date entered.. The results on the page which can be entered are also in list format which means there is more than one input field.

Im getting the order id to alert but the date from the corresponding row I am not

See my code:

HTML/PHP:

```
<td>Test company</td>
<td><input type="text" id="ord<?php echo $row['orderid']?>" value="10/11/2015"></td>
<td><button class="updateOrd" ordid="<?php echo $row['orderid']?>">Add Date to Order</button></td>

<td>Test company2</td>
<td><input type="text" id="ord<?php echo $row['orderid']?>" value="10/11/2015"></td>
<td><button class="updateOrd" ordid="<?php echo $row['orderid']?>">Add Date to Order</button></td>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.updateOrd', function(e) {

    var ordid = $(this).attr('ordid');
    var date = $('input#ord'.ordid).val();

    alert(ordid);
    alert(date);

});
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `data-ordid=""` instead of `ordid=""`. This way your HTML is valid.

And the problem is this:

```
var date = $('input#ord'.ordid).val();
```

It should be:

```
var date = $('input#ord' + ordid).val();
```

For the record this is how you combine strings and vars:

```
-----------------------------
----- JavaScript ---- + -----
-----     PHP    ---- . -----
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate 'input#ord' + ordid

```
$(document).on('click', '.updateOrd', function(e) {

    var ordid = $(this).attr('ordid');
    var date = $('input#ord' + ordid).val();

    alert(ordid);
    alert(date);

});
```

**Hope this helps!**